# Proof By Contradiction Divisibility Question

Tags: proof-writing

Use prove by contradiction to prove that for all integers p , q and r, if p is not divisible by qr then p is not divisible by q

Comment: Better check more carefully what the exercise is asking for. If you still have a question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When P is divisible by qr , it must be divisible by q. [[ Eg , 75 is divisible by 5x3 , thus 75 divisible by 3 ]] When P is not divisible by qr , it may or may not be divisible by q [[ Eg , 75 is not divisible by 3x2 , yet 75 is divisible by 3 , while 75 is not divisible by 2 ]]